# Issue with index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing issue while loading data a tab separated file with pandas. It assigns the first columns as index and whole data is shifted to the left. The abstract column as a result has NaN value. If I do reset_index on the dataframe, it will drop the index. How to fix this issue.

```
data = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='\t')
data.head()
```

[image]

Adding screenshot of TSV file
[image]

Comment: The issue is not reproducible with the given info. Can you please add more context to it. How does your CSV look like?

Comment: @PubuduSitinamaluwa I have added a screenshot of the tsv file

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem. It works for me. Do you have multiple sheets in the file in any case?

Comment: @PubuduSitinamaluwa There is only one sheet. I converted the tsv into csv file and it is working as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code...

```
data = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='\t')
data.drop(index=0, inplace=True)
data.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, setting `index_col=False` when reading the CSV can be used to force pandas to not use the first column as the index.

[Reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)